# Android Studio - Failed with error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: android

I have a project on GitHub and an using Android Studio. I've had VCS setup and have been using it but now I'm getting "Failed with error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository." error message when I try to push it. If I use the GitHub app I can Sync the project.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the origin?

You can type "git remote show origin" in the terminal in the Aandroid Studio. Maybe something changed there.

Comment: If I enter any git commands in the terminal in AS I get
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: When I launch powershell from the GitHub app I get a list of the URL and all the remote and local branches and it all look correct.